# How long can coronavirus last outside the human body?

Tags: coronavirus

This article

[enter link description here](https://www.livescience.com/how-long-coronavirus-last-surfaces.html)

states that one study said it can last up to 72 hours, and that other study concluded that ***if*** the new coronavirus resembles other human coronaviruses, it could last up to 9 days.

Moreover, an image with it's been circulating in my country with the logo of the ministery of health, it says it can last up to 5 days.

How long can coronavirus SARS-CoV-2 last outside the human body?

Comment: It can live indefinitely in bats one assumes

Comment: That article contains data from the very latest research. Is there reason to doubt it?